# Is there any way to trigger a workflow on GitHub actions that will execute after N hours from another workflow that succeeded?

Tags: github-actions, cicd

For example, I have 2 pipelines: `A` and `B`.

I want to trigger `B` pipeline N hours after `A` is executed.

Comment: What is your use case? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to send a notification after 7 hours a pipeline is finished.